# MaskedInputFormatter wont let me input numbers

Tags: flutter, inputformatter

I am using a mask for Austrailia `+61 (###) ###-####`. I need the number to be formatted to `+61 (123) 456-7890`. The solution works with `PhoneInputFormatter`. However, `PhoneInputFormatter` does not allow for formatting like `()` and `-`.

```dart
TextFormField(
  keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
  autocorrect: false,
  inputFormatters: [
    MaskedInputFormater('+61 (000) 000-0000')
  ],
  // .. etc
);
```

The above mask will not allow to enter either `1` or `6`. How can I fix the issue to both keep the formatting and let user type the digits as well?

Comment: which package you are using

Answer (score 0):

There are some typo issue, try this for [`mask_text_input_formatter`](https://pub.dev/packages/mask_text_input_formatter)

```dart
MaskTextInputFormatter(mask: '+61 (000) 000-0000')
```

Answer (score 0):

A quick glance at https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_multi_formatter seems to indicate that `PhoneInputFormatter` does allow for formatting with `()` and `-`.

Can you confirm that this is not the case?

```
PhoneInputFormatter.replacePhoneMask(
    countryCode: 'RU',
    newMask: '+0 (000) 000 00 00',
);
PhoneInputFormatter.addAlternativePhoneMasks(
    countryCode: 'BR',
    alternativeMasks: [
    '+00 (00) 0000-0000',
    '+(00) 00000',
    '+00 (00) 00-0000',
    ],
);
```